# Check 2 keys for Vacant

Tags: rust, hashmap

I am using the `HashMap` to store some of the value. Now I want to check whether `HashMap` contains keys, if not insert data else return `HashMap` is not empty. Below code explain that I am checking for product id, but I want to check for 2 keys product key and product url.

```rs
use std::collections::hash_map::Entry::Vacant;

pub struct Products<DB>
where
DB: DatabaseProvider,
{
    database: DB,
    products: HashMap<String, Product>,
}

pub struct Product {
    pub product_id: String,
    pub created: String,
    pub product_description: String,
    pub product_url: String,
}

pub async fn get_product_store_hashmap(&mut self) -> Result<()>
{
    // calling the api here, once response is received, store in hashmap
    let product = Product {
        product_id: somedata,
        created: somedata,
        product_description: somedata,
        product_url:somedata,
    };
    self.products.insert(product_id.clone(), product);
}


pub async fn insertProduct(&mut self, product:Product) -> Result<()> {

    // How to check two keys are contains value.
    if let Vacant(entry:Vacant::entry<(string,Product)) = self.product.entry(product_id) {
        // insert the data

    } else {
        // retun no product id found
    }

}
```

Comment: why do you insert data if you already have an entry? do you rather mean you want to update it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map.contains_key` to test.

Example:

```rust
fn insertProduct(map: &mut HashMap<String, Product>, product: Product) -> Result<()> {
    if map.contains_key(product.product_id) || map.contains_key(product.product_url)  {
        Err()
    } else {
        map.insert(product.product_id, Product);
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Vacant` and `Occupied` to check if key already exists or not and return result according using `match`

```rs
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::collections::hash_map::Entry::{Vacant, Occupied};
use std::io::ErrorKind;

fn main() {
    let mut h: HashMap<&str, u8>  = HashMap::new();
    let value: &str = "a";
    // h.entry(value).or_insert(1); // <- uncomment to get err result
    let result = match h.entry(value) {
        Vacant(entry) => {
          entry.insert(1);
          Ok(())
        },
        Occupied(_) => Err(ErrorKind::AlreadyExists)
    };
    
    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

[`Playground`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b1812c41e4e0a73c7abf8f27a7fd4bb1)